# How to call django template in order to use it through Jquery?

Tags: jquery, python, django, forms

I've installed the django-newsletter application, and customized the subscribing form. But, right now, I'd like to print it through a Jquery Overlay, instead of a flatpage containing that form. 
Problem is I don't know how to include this flatpages elements into every page where the link calling the overlay will be present; and I don't know which approach would be the most performant.

Please light my way :)
Thank you!

Comment: When you said print, did you actually mean present the form in a jQuery overlay?

Comment: Absolutely, sorry for my english ;)
I meant, display that form in the overlay :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Django view which renders just the HTML for the form using your preferred template. Then use $.ajax() with dataType: "html" to get the code for the form for use in your overlay.

Comment: Seems a pretty way to do this I guess, but I'm not very experimented in the Ajax thing :-) Will that be more performant rather than include my template in the desired page and "rel" it as an overlay?

Comment: The ajax method might be slightly slower from the time the user clicks the link until when the overlay including the form appears because of the extra GET request going on in the background. However, that delay should not be significant. I find it to be a more elegant solution than hiding the form HTML somewhere in every page.

Answer (score 1):

So this kind of expands in more detail what @Nathan suggested.

#### Take one

First, you can publish the subscription form in every template where you think the user will click the newsletter subscription link. The form is hidden and will be presented once overlay triggers it for display.

```
{# newsletter_subscribe_request_form_overlay.html #}

{% if newsletter_subscribe_request_form %}
  <div id="newsletter_subscribe_request_form_overlay" class="simple_overlay">
    <form action="{% url newsletter_subscribe_request %}" method="POST">
      {{ newsletter_subscribe_request_form.as_p }}
      <input type="submit" value="Subscribe to the newsletter" />
      {% csrf_token %}
    </form>
  </div>
{% endif %}

{# now, in the templates where the overlay action link will be present #}
{# ...at the very bottom, just before the `BODY` element closing tag #}

{% include 'newsletter_subscribe_request_form_overlay.html' %}
```

Ok, so this would basically allow you to put a hidden subscription form on any page where you'd like to present it with the overlay. What's left now is to add the `newsletter_subscribe_request_form` to the template context. You can do this by either updating the views to add the form to the context, or you could create a context processor. Personally, I'd prefer the context processor:

```
from newsletter.models import Subscription
from newsletter.forms import SubscribeRequestForm

def newsletter_subscribe_request_form_overlay(request):
    '''
    Inserts a newsletter subscribe request form into the context
    for every user that's not yet subscribed.
    '''

    try:
        Subscription.objects.get(user=request.user)
        # object exists, user is already subscribed
        return {} 
    except Subscription.DoesNotExist:
        # object doesn't exist, push the form to the context
        return {'newsletter_subscribe_request_form': SubscribeRequestForm()}
    except:
        # something unexpected happened, or I messed up
        return {}
```

So that about wraps up this approach. This one is pretty simple since it only includes writing a simple template, including it in other templates and then having a context processor that will push the form into the template context for unsubscribed users.

The flipside is that, depending on your team or personal preferences, this could be too much magic to handle. Unless you document the approach somewhere, it's going to be a bit unintuitive where does `newsletter_subscribe_request_form` in the context come from (the view?; one of the context processors?) and you may also have to go through a big template inheritance line to figure out where `newsletter_subscribe_request_form_overlay.html` was included. Not to mention, your doing an additional database query per request.

What this is great for, though, is that you can also add the unsubscribe form to the context if the user is subscribed, and depending which of the two is present, you could dynamically change the link titles between "Subscribe" and "Unsubscribe", which would be one of those small boons you can give to your users.

#### Take two

The second approach is to create a simple `CreateView` that you could fetch via an Ajax call and present the content in the overlay interactively.

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from newsletter.forms import SubscribeRequestForm
from django.http import HttpResponseBadRequest

class AjaxSubscriptionRequestView(CreateView):
     ''''
     A simple subscription create view that returns a 
     subscription form in the response for Ajax calls
     ''''

     http_method_names = ['get',]
     form_class = SubscribeRequestForm
     template_name = 'newsletter_subscribe_request_form_overlay.html'

     def get_initial(self):
         return {'user': self.request.user}

     def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         if not request.is_ajax():
             return HttpResponseBadRequest()
         else:
             return super(AjaxSubscriptionRequestView, self).get(request,
                                                                 *args, **kwargs)
```

So we're using the same template as in the first example, so we're just returning the form in the response. Now it's just a matter of fetching the form and presenting it in an overlay once it's retrieved.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function newsletterSubscribeRequestFormOverlay(eventObject) {
        eventObject.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: "{% url ajax-subscription-request %}",
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                $('body').append(html);
                $('.simple_overlay').overlay();
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<a href="{% url newsletter_subscribe_request %}" 
   onclick="javascript: newsletterSubscribeRequestFormOverlay(event);">
   Subscribe to our newsletter
</a>
```

Of course, this would need some additional spit and polish. You could present the overlay with a spinner until you get the response with the form HTML, to provide users with some form of feedback when they click the subscription link.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd also prefer doing it in ajax, but just for future reference,
if you want to include html or variables in every request, you can do that in context processors, and to include subtemplates there's an include tag, which you could use in a base template.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#include